# Adding Gluon UI library to a JavaFX Desktop application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml, gluon

I am working on a desktop application using JavaFX, FXMLs (using Scene Builder) and JDBC on IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.
I added Gluon library to the Scene Builder successfully but when I exported the FXML file to IntelliJ it did not recognize the Gluon components, the problem obviously is adding Gluon Library to IntelliJ which I couldn't do.
Question is, How to add Gluon library to IntelliJ? I checked several forums and I didn't figure it out.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-project-library Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @b3p0 sort of, I'm currently stuck on importing it but I found it through your way

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? Follow the guide and choose the correct .jar file. There's also a [Gluon plugin for IntelliJ](https://gluonhq.com/the-new-gluon-plugin-for-intellij-idea/) which might help.

Comment: @b3p0 i imported both `com.gluonhq.charm.down.common.JavaFXPlatform` and `com.gluonhq.charm.down.android.AndroidPlatform` but it still can't recognize the components

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle for managing the dependencies?

Comment: @Boris I am using Maven for this particular project

Comment: Please add the corresponding POM configuration to the question then.

Comment: @Boris I can't find it in my hierarchy

Comment: Then how did you add Gluon library to the Scene Builder?

Comment: @Boris I added it through the standalone Scene builder not through IntelliJ, when I save the file as FXML and add it to the project's in IntelliJ it does not recognize "Avatar" and "AutoCompleteTextField" components

Comment: Provide screenshots describing the problem you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use [Gluon Mobile](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.2/) classes from the `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control` package, for example, [Avatar](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/Avatar.html) and [AutoCompleteTextField](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/AutoCompleteTextField.html) you have to include the [Charm Glisten](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gluonhq/charm-glisten) dependency from the Gluon Nexus repository:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
    <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>gluon-nexus-repository</id>
    <url>http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```